# QVBoxLayout in QScrollWidget is not updating Sizes

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have a QVBoxLayout as a pointer in my window and want to add Widgets dynamically (When the user presses a button, a Widget is added to the VBoxLayout). The VBoxLayout is set as Layout in the ScrollArea. But if I add Widgets to the VBoxLayout, the size of the VBoxLayout does not change and everything gets crumpled.

```
  m_ControlsLayout = new QVBoxLayout; //A member variable to add things later
  {
    QPushButton *PushButton = new QPushButton(tr("Add a new control"));
    connect(PushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addControl())); //Adds it
    m_ControlsLayout->addWidget(PushButton, 1);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)  //I am adding 10 useless Widgets to fill the space
    addControl();

  QScrollArea *ScrollArea = new QScrollArea;
  connect(this)
  ScrollArea->setWidget(Layout2Widget(m_ControlsLayout));
```

The addControl() Slot just adds a Widget:

```
  m_ControlsLayout->addWidget(new ControlWidget);
```

I think I have to tell the QScrollArea that it should update its heights.

Comment: Have you tried `scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true)`?

Comment: I tried right now and if I add this, the VBoxLayout gets resized to the height of the ScrollArea. No scrollbars appear and everything is very small (or if there are less widgets, everything is stretched)

Answer (score 0):

When using a scroll area to display the contents of a custom widget "ControlWidget", it is important to ensure that the size hint of the child widget is set to a suitable value.
Re implement, virtual function"QSize QWidget::sizeHint ()" on your custom widget class.